# MySQL Order By Slows down Joins

Tags: mysql, join, sql-order-by

I have problem with is query

```
SELECT *
FROM files f
LEFT JOIN xfiles x ON x.hash = f.bhash
LEFT JOIN cate c ON c.id = f.cate
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = f.user
LEFT JOIN userslev ul ON u.id_lev = ul.id
LEFT JOIN (

SELECT DISTINCT x.hash, s.iis
FROM anno x
JOIN seb s ON s.iis = x.icc
WHERE x.le =0
AND (
x.eve =0
OR x.eve =2
)
GROUP BY  `x`.`hash`
) AS tabel2 ON tabel2.hash = f.bhash
WHERE f.see + IFNULL( x.see, 0 ) + f.lee + IFNULL( x.lee, 0 ) >0
ORDER BY f.added DESC
```

Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 22,083 total, Query took 9.6523 sec)

as you can see , it takes 9 sec !

but without 'order by'

```
SELECT *
FROM files f
LEFT JOIN xfiles x ON x.hash = f.bhash
LEFT JOIN cate c ON c.id = f.cate
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = f.user
LEFT JOIN userslev ul ON u.id_lev = ul.id
LEFT JOIN (

SELECT DISTINCT x.hash, s.iis
FROM anno x
JOIN seb s ON s.iis = x.icc
WHERE x.le =0
AND (
x.eve =0
OR x.eve =2
)
GROUP BY  `x`.`hash`
) AS tabel2 ON tabel2.hash = f.bhash
WHERE f.see + IFNULL( x.see, 0 ) + f.lee + IFNULL( x.lee, 0 ) >0
```

Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 22,083 total, Query took 0.0241 sec)

only 0.0241 sec :)

............

is there a way to have ' order by' with good-time?

............

indexes:

```
Indexes: (files)

Action  Keyname Type    Unique  Packed  Column  Cardinality Collation   Null    Comment
 Edit    Drop   PRIMARY BTREE   Yes No  ihash   27815   A       
 Edit    Drop   filename    BTREE   No  No  filename    27815   A       
 Edit    Drop   cate    BTREE   No  No  cate    45  A       
 Edit    Drop   user    BTREE   No  No  user    1264    A       
 Edit    Drop   bhash   BTREE   No  No  bhash (20)  27815   A       
 Edit    Drop   added   BTREE   No  No  added   27815   A       
 Edit    Drop   filename_2  FULLTEXT    No  No  filename    1           



Indexes: (xfiles)

Action  Keyname Type    Unique  Packed  Column  Cardinality Collation   Null    Comment
 Edit    Drop   PRIMARY BTREE   Yes No  id  8196    A       
 Edit    Drop   hash    BTREE   Yes No  hash    8196    A       
 Edit    Drop   see BTREE   No  No  see 37  A       
 Edit    Drop   leec    BTREE   No  No  lee25   A   


Indexes: (cate)

Action  Keyname Type    Unique  Packed  Column  Cardinality Collation   Null    Comment
 Edit    Drop   PRIMARY BTREE   Yes No  id  51  A   


Indexes: (users)

Action  Keyname Type    Unique  Packed  Column  Cardinality Collation   Null    Comment
 Edit    Drop   PRIMARY BTREE   Yes No  id  39776   A       
 Edit    Drop   username    BTREE   Yes No  username    39776   A       
 Edit    Drop   id_lev  BTREE   No  No  id_lev  19  A       


Indexes: (userslev)

Action  Keyname Type    Unique  Packed  Column  Cardinality Collation   Null    Comment
 Edit    Drop   base    BTREE   Yes No  id  22  A       


Indexes: (anno)

Action  Keyname Type    Unique  Packed  Column  Cardinality Collation   Null    Comment
 Edit    Drop   PRIMARY BTREE   Yes No  id  23636   A       
 Edit    Drop   icc BTREE   No  No  icc 2626    A       
 Edit    Drop   eve BTREE   No  No  eve 8   A       
 Edit    Drop   hash    BTREE   No  No  hash    5909    A       
 Edit    Drop   le  BTREE   No  No  le  875 A   


Indexes: (seb)

Action  Keyname Type    Unique  Packed  Column  Cardinality Collation   Null    Comment
 Edit    Drop   PRIMARY BTREE   Yes No  id  58  A       
 Edit    Drop   iis BTREE   Yes No  iis 58  A   YES
```

EXPLAIN:

```
id          select_type     table       type            possible_keys       key         key_len         ref         rows    Extra
1               PRIMARY     f           ALL             NULL                NULL        NULL            NULL        27819   Using temporary; Using filesort
1               PRIMARY     x           eq_ref          hash                hash        20              f.bhash     1       Using where
1               PRIMARY     c           eq_ref          PRIMARY             PRIMARY     4               f.cate      1   
1               PRIMARY     u           eq_ref          PRIMARY             PRIMARY     4               f.user      1   
1               PRIMARY     ul          eq_ref          base                base        4               u.id_lev    1   
1               PRIMARY     <derived2>  ALL             NULL                NULL        NULL            NULL        1176    
2               DERIVED     s           index           iis                 iis         5               NULL        58      Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
2               DERIVED     x           ref             icc,eve,le          icc         4               s.iis       9       Using where
```

Comment: Did you try indexing `f.added` column?

Comment: @raina77ow it's indexed but I forget to put it

Comment: maybe the index is sorted ASC while you need your results to be sorted DESC

Comment: Try replacing the `WHERE f.see + IFNULL( x.see, 0 ) + f.lee + IFNULL( x.lee, 0 ) >0` with `WHERE (f.see>0 OR x.see>0 OR f.lee>0 OR x.lee>0)`

Comment: @Giuseppe tried ASC , No change

Comment: @ypercube tried that and even deleted 'where' , No change at all

Comment: Perhaps one of your `LEFT JOIN` tables has interaction effects. I am particularly looking at the subquery

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of information on optimizing for order by here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

Can you post both explains so we can see what the difference in the query plan is?